# Jquery get value of child div and replace text elsewhere on page

Tags: jquery, html, css, text, replace

I have a fiddle here to explain what I am using,
https://jsfiddle.net/wvz9p3e7/1/

This is usually in PHP and has a loop for 7 or 8 garments, so what I want to do, is in the window on the right in the fiddle, when you click one of the boxes, the window on the right fills with the correct Garment Id and Base price,

I can get the garment ID to work, but how to i get JS to find the base price and fill out the text on the right?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $(".garment-select").click(function(event) {
                $("#garmentID").text(event.target.id);
                $(".garment-select").not(this).removeClass('selectecGarment');
                $(this).toggleClass( "selectecGarment" );
            });

            $(".garmentPanel > .").click(function(event) {
                $("#garmentID").text(event.target.id);
            });

        });
```

Comment: Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/wvz9p3e7/2/) Demo

Comment: Just a small note: You are using the same `id` in different elements. `Id` should be unique and only be used once per page.

Comment: Also, there's no just a `.` selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to solve this. Straight forward:

```
$(".garmentPanel").click(function() {
     $("#garmentID").text($(this).attr('id'));
     $("#garmentBasePrice").text($(this).find('.garmentPrice').text());
});
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wvz9p3e7/7/)

Answer (score 0):

use this jQuery statement to do retrieve that price -

```
$('#garmentBasePrice').html($(this).next().next().text());
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wvz9p3e7/6/)